# Maximum resolution problem when external monitor is connected via KVM Switch

Tags: kvm-virtualization, display-resolution

I use a laptop with Ubuntu (15.04) and output on monitor (LG E2240). Everything is OK, the maximum resolution is 1920x1080 ( the maximum resolution supported by the monitor). When I connect a KVM Switch (model: 41UA USB KVM Switch) resolution is limited to 1024x768. How to obtain maximum resolution using this KVM Switch? I have to do some settings?I need to search and install any driver?
Wait for response!
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This is a typical case caused by EDID/DDC communication from the connected and shared monitor DID NOT successfully and correctly passed between:
1. Connected systems to KVM switch, 
2. or the shared monitor to the KVM switch.

Normally, it is very easy to be solve - If the video sharing is for Sharing DVI monitor, then go for DVI-EDID emulator - let it connected between your shared system and the new DVI monitor. 
u
Rex W